# Clash of brothers?

Tags: translation

Google Translate outputs for:

```
兄弟鬩牆，二
```

the following:

```
Clash between the brothers.
```

I know it is naive to try machine translation for guessing the meaning, but can somebody help me get Chinese counterpart for the word Clash in the source phrase?

UPDATE: here are two texts containing this phrase:

1. 熱血時報|大香港早晨(347)湯家驊退黨辭職 早過公民黨執政/田氏兄弟鬩牆，二少望脫離大哥陰影/梁文道挑機撩筆戰，陶傑以「不回應」去「回應」/國泰服務澳牛化？http://t.co/qWS7mBNd76
2. "【大香港早晨】第347集：湯家驊退黨辭職 早過公民黨執政/田氏兄弟鬩牆，二少望脫離大哥陰影/梁文道挑機撩筆戰，陶傑以「不回應」去「回應」/國泰服務澳牛化？節目連結

Answer (score 1):

阋墙 is a bit bookish. 冲突 is more common to describe a clash.

Comment: thanks I have found 冲突 in my dictionary as well. When you say "bookish" -- do you mean 阋墙 wouldn't be used too often in spoken language / social media channels?

Answer (score 1):

兄弟之战 ([Clash of Lords](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igg.clashoflords2tw&hl=zh-TW) goes by the name 领主之战, so 之战 is acceptable or even preferrable).

Comment: The more authentic Clash of Clans, however, is translated into 部落冲突 in both CHS and CHT. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans&hl=zh-TW

Comment: And Clash of the Titans (2010) is 诸神之战. Clash of the Gods is 诸神之战. Clash of the Damned is 诅咒之战. Clash of the Mages: 魔法师之战. Clash of Heroes: 英雄之战. And tons of more 'Clash'-es with 之战.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Is word clash separateable from the source phrase 兄弟鬩牆，二 ? Or it can't be extracted?

Comment: I don't exactly know where 兄弟鬩牆 comes from, Google Translate uses statistical translation, so it doesn't really translate your query, but gives you something that is the most likely based on corpora. But it is definitely not a good translation, based on examples what @NS.X. and I have quoted here you have better options.

Comment: 兄弟鬩牆 comes from 《[詩經‧小雅‧鹿鳴之什‧常棣](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E8%A9%A9%E7%B6%93/%E5%B8%B8%E6%A3%A3)》(the full sentence is 兄弟鬩于牆，外禦其務). It is kind of a [Chengyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu).

Comment: I have just added the two examples where I have found the reported phrase. Do they change the meaning of what we have discussed here in any way?